# How to trace event if i change a wallpaper in my device

Tags: java, android, service

I am creating an application in which i am setting a gallery of images with shuffling effect on wallpaper. shuffling effect is working if app is in background.
But the problem is when i change my wallpaper from my device to set on home screen(not from application but select form wallpapers of device), that wallpaper is setting on my home screen and the shuffling effect remains continue(because i think service is running). Can someone please tell me what is the issue and how to solve this. This is my service class:

```
public class WallpaperService extends Service {
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
int counter = 0;
Bitmap bmImg = null;
int seconds;
public WallpaperService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flag, startId);
    arrayList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("image_url");
    seconds = intent.getIntExtra("seconds", 5000 * 60);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    SaveWallpaperAsync async = new SaveWallpaperAsync();
    async.execute();
           return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    myAlarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartPendingIntent);
}

public class SaveWallpaperAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
    URL ImageUrl;
    Bitmap bmImg = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(WallpaperService.this, "downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InputStream is = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            try {
                ImageUrl = new URL(arrayList.get(i));
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ImageUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                is = conn.getInputStream();

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
                saveImageToInternalStorage(bmImg, i);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(WallpaperService.this, "Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        createNotificationIcon();
    }
}

protected String saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap, int index) {

    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Dark Wallpapers/");
    if (!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(dir, "UniqueFileName" + index + ".jpg");

    try {
        OutputStream stream = null;
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
    return savedImageURI.toString();
}

private Bitmap loadImageFromStorage(int counter) {
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Dark Wallpapers/", "UniqueFileName" + counter + ".jpg");
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}

public void createNotificationIcon() {
    final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  counter += 1;
                                  if (counter < arrayList.size()) {
                                      try {
                                          wallpaperManager.setBitmap(loadImageFromStorage(counter));
                                          wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(1080, 1920);
                                      } catch (IOException e) {
                                          e.printStackTrace();
                                      }
                                  } else if (counter == arrayList.size()) {
                                      counter = 0;
                                      try {
                                          wallpaperManager.setBitmap(loadImageFromStorage(counter));
                                          wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(1080, 1920);
                                      } catch (IOException e) {
                                          e.printStackTrace();
                                      }
                                  }

                              }

                          },
            0,
            seconds);

}}
```

This is how i called it from activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, WallpaperService.class);
intent.putExtra("image_url", img_urls);
            intent.putExtra("seconds", 60);
            intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
            startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood well you would like to get an "event" (or just to know...) when the home wallpaper is changed. Is it right?
Maybe you would like to stop your Service if it detects that the User wants to set a fixed wallpaper from that moment.

There isn't any Event to do this, but there is a solution: remember which wallpaper you have automatically changed from the App (maybe memorize the path+filename in a file in your /xxxxx/files folder) and then check the Current Wallpaper just before trying to set the new one, using this:

`WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();`

In this way if the Current Wallpaper is the same of your last and memorized filename than there is a 99% of chance that the user doesn't set a fixed one by his/her own. (the remaining 1% could be the possibility that the user manually sets the SAME wallpaper you automatically set as the last one, but it's very-very rare)